# mongodb $or within $and will not use index

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in mongo db with index on "x" column. the following query work fine.

```
db.col.find({'$or': [{'x': '1'}, {'x': '2'}]})
```

The explain() method confirms that mongo db uses the index on "x". Adding another operator (whether $or or $and) to the above statement will somehow corrupt the query. A simple $and with just one operand (that I expected mongo to completely ignore it) makes mongo not to use the index:

```
db.col.find({"$and": [{'$or': [{'x': '1'}, {'x': '2'}]}]})
```

expain() results indicates that mongo scans all the documents and is not using index, anymore.

Comment: This is a known flaw, if you look at this JIRA: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3192 you will notice this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3327 is linked and relates directly to it